# How to implement youtube.search.list with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api

I'm trying to make `youtube.search.list` working with `Node.js`. It looks like I can successfully authenticate with `YouTube API` v.3.0 but when I run `youtube.search.list` I get empty result set.

There is either stupid error in the code or I make incorrect request on `YouTube API`.

Here is the code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var youtubeV3 = google.youtube({ version: 'v3', auth: 'MY_API_KEY' });

var request = youtubeV3.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    q: 'Cat',
    maxResults: 50,
    order: 'date',
    safeSearch: 'moderate',
    videoEmbeddable: true
});

// console.log('Here we start search');
for (var i in request.items) {
    var item = request.items[i];
    console.log('Title: ', item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
}
```

In order to check what I get back from API I run `console.log(request)` and get empty object.

Comment: I have no experience on this but I'd check https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword
I think there should be an execute() before you get results, good luck and report back if you get it working.

Comment: @diynevala, I spent many on the resource you referenced with no positive result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddeling around with the API a little, I came up with the following, working code:

```
var google = require('googleapis'),
    youtubeV3 = google.youtube( { version: 'v3', auth: 'API_KEY' } );

var request =  youtubeV3.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    q: 'Cat',
    maxResults: 50,
    order: 'date',
    safeSearch: 'moderate',
    videoEmbeddable: true
}, (err,response) => {
  // your code here
});
```

Despite the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) telling one to use execute, [the repository of google apis on Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) tells one to use that node callback pattern, which turned out to work.

Comment: This example is exactly what I suggested in my comment (via documentation) but was too lazy to make it an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. When I run the code I get the following exception: request.execute() is not a function

Comment: try `console.log(request);` to see what the request is.

Comment: @diynevala, as I said before. I get empty object

Comment: @IgorM Revised the answer.

Comment: @Sirko. Works! Thanks a lot! The callback approach did it